# Is there any python package that I can use to plot the streamline moving water?

Tags: python, plot, 2d, streamline

I have time series of veracity (both X and Y directions) in 2D array format. Then, I want to plot the streamline for water flowing as shown in the attached figure. So, I would like to ask if anyone knows the Python Package that can use to plot such below figure.

Your help is really appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhygB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Plotly

```
pip install plotly
```

Check the document [Streamline Plots in Python](https://plotly.com/python/streamline-plots/) for details.